# How to get the Animation in Scrolling Recyclerview as given in the video.?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

Hello here the YouTube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtaBVhsxm9A

In this video there is a animation on scrolling of recyclerview on the top item of the list gets the height expansion how can I achieve it ? Please help with anything thanks.

Comment: you should detect, when the previous item starts going out of screen, and expand the next item's height. There is no easy way of doing it.

Comment: @VladMatvienko can you tell me how can I detect if it is out of screen or not  ?

Comment: set onScroll listener, and check the position of the top of the view relative to the screen top.

Comment: I have tried with                         'visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();'  but not able to do it

Comment: `not able to do it` what was the problem? Why you were not able?

Comment: I am not getting the top position with it

Comment: and what you get instead?

Comment: I am getting the visible item position perfectly but If it is not scrolled properly for example : When I scroll the list till the divider line of first item is shown It is giving me the visible item as one

Comment: and why you think that it is wrong? the #0 item is gone, and not visible, only the divider is visible. So the #1 item is now first visible.

Comment: How can I scroll a single item at a time is it possible like vertical  snapp recycler ?

Comment: `vertical snapp recycler` don't know what it is. And it is not in scope of this question.